# Rails: Passing API JSON Response to View, without Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, decorator

Disclaimer: I'm doing something which may qualify for Code Smell of 2015 Award. Using rails 4.2, no javascript or anything like that.

I have a form into which users input their data. With this data I call a third-party API which will remain nameless. :)

I have no model, I'm not persisting anything. (Part of a larger app, not a one-pager.) Thus when faced with presenting the user with the response, I find myself stuck on how to render the data properly into a view. The response contains an array of hashes which I obviously intend to present the user.

I render the form into widgets/new, etc, create and process the request, etc, but then what?

I thought maybe I could make use of decorators to do my dirty work but not sure how to actually get the user off to the respective view. I don't care which view. Call it a widget_path.

```
WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    render :new
  end      

  def create
    # preparing request        
    ...
    # data = response, each_serializer, WidgetSerializer, root: false
    # data = WidgetDecorator.new(render_serialized(response, WidgetSerializer))
    # @data = WidgetDecorator.new(JSON.parse(response))
    # redirect_to ??_path ... and take your @data with you
  end
end
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of *Model* is unfortunately corrupted by Rails itself (sorry).
A model is *business logic* **not an ActiveRecord::Base** (not necessarily). Controller methods shouldn't be big, ~5 lines long is probably the maximum with a ~100 lines max per controller file. Try to stick with this and it will automatically correct good chunck of code smells.

Anyway, you may handle this with a *Model*, as a PORO (plain old ruby object).

```
class MyApiResponse

  attr_reader :myapikey
  attr_reader :whatever

  def initialize(myapikey, whatever)
    @myapikey = myapikey
    @whatever = whatever
  end

  def get
    @_response ||= JSON.parse(run_api_stuff(myapikey))
  end

end
```

So in controller you would do something like

```
def create
  myapiresponse = MyApiResonse.new(myapikey, whatever)
  @response     = myapiresponse.get
end
```

Last but not least, you can't pass what you obtained through the API in the redirect. You are subject to HTTP limits so, you have a limit on GET params size, a limit on session and you can't redirect to a POST. You have 3 options

1. Best is store last api request for given user in the database and fetch it back through an ID (which will travel through the redirect)
2. Store it in session if request is really small (and you must ensure it is small!)
3. Perform the API request again after the redirect, horrible. Otherwise perform the API request **only** after redirect, not sure if this is an option though

Comment: Gotcha, thanks @Fire, quite helpful. I'm looking at #1. Is it feasible to just persist whatever JSON response as a string and parse on the other side you think?

Comment: Yes it should be definitely ok. However it can be easier if you just store (for current user) a `last_response` field, so you don't even need an id. If you are using postgresql 9.3+, there is JSON field type available which is great, otherwise just call `to_json` on your response and store it in any `text` field, being it a `last_response` or a proper table.

Comment: This is how I am handling API data as well. Having trouble figuring out the best way to deal with forms, though